# How to extract and delete some text in a file and delete it in C++

Tags: c++, text

I'm looking for deleting some line of text in a file generated in C++.
In fact, i received a file on my server made with the microsoft library C++ Rest SDK aka Casablanca.

I extracted my content request and inserted it in a file.
Here is an exemple of what i got now in my file:

"--------------------------"

----------------------------379412310113082987734398
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2.png"
Content-Type: image/png

‰PNG

IHDR  Å   }   \Mï   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa    pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d  0IDATx^íÁkG‡}ÌÑ@rÌÿ Ó Œ<—qbaã‘  ’L&AA‘uPŒû0F
Âm+³³((dÇ…`fa6Q´ŠÀ‹‚«%b&ƒµ,{˜›î›öU½êîêîšQ÷¸4VÏü¾ƒ]SÕ]ÕÝRªêê©wî  €
àS  °|
  v€O Àð)  Ø>  ;À§`ø  ì Ÿ €àS  °|

BLABLABLA the rest of the content of my file....

----------------------------379412310113082987734398--

I would like to delete this lines:
----------------------------379412310113082987734398
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2.png"
Content-Type: image/png
(with the space here)
----------------------------379412310113082987734398--

I would like to know how to delete this for generating my binary file.
Thanks in advance for your precious help.

---------------------------"

Answer (score 0):

you could read your file and write a new file excluding the line that you don't want.

To do that you can iterate your file and check every line with a regular expression.

The regular expression allow you to specify the form that your input has to have.

You should identify which part of your input is fixed and which one is variable, in order to build up the correct regular expression.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Bye

---

I put here a little code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string inputLine="----------------------------379412310113082987734398 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"2.png\" Content-Type: image/png ";
    regex regularExpression("[-]+[0-9]+ Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\".+\"; filename=\".+\" Content-Type: .+ ");

    if(regex_match(inputLine,regularExpression))
        cout<<"REGEX OK"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"REGEX FAIL"<<endl;
}
```

the inputLine is your line.
The regular expression is the way to specify the format of your input.

this

```
"[-]+[0-9]+ Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\".+\"; filename=\".+\" Content-Type: .+ "
```

means that your input is composed by:

- 1 or more "-" carachers [-]+
- 1 or more numbers [0-9]+
- a fixed string 
  << Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\".+\"; filename=\".+\" Content-Type: .+ >> in which the content of name="" and filename=\".+\" can be anything and the Content-Type can be anything.
  Note the spaces at the beginning and the end of the string.

Note that i have supposed that the variable parts are:

- number of "-"
- number of digits
- name
- filename
- Content-Type

if the format of your input is different you have to modify the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks ilroci, the problem he take "ëPNG" and "0",  on my file too.
Do you have an idea how to not take it or consider it ?
I need it because i will generate a file in binary than i receive from an http request

Comment: Thanks ilroci, but what i need is, if it's thios, i don't take it, otherwise it's ok.
But i can't get the good content.
Or do you know how i can delete the current line on that code ?
And it take "‰PNG" and "0", but i would like to not consider them with the regex.
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: hi, you can't delete the line directly from the file. you have to create a new file. 
The regex is the best solution i got. Maybe someone else will give you a better solution. bye!

Answer (score -1):

Open the file in binary mode, read lines from the infile and write them one by one to the outfile until you get to a line that starts with "----------------------------379412310113082987734398" (use strncmp() to check for this condition).

Then discard that line without writing it. Then continue reading (and discarding) lines until you get to a line that again matches "----------------------------379412310113082987734398".

Then read in and write out the remaining lines.

Comment: I don't think that _opening in binary mode_ would really help in this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP specified binary, so binary it is.

Comment: The OP didn't specify a lot anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ uh, OK? That doesn't change the fact that OP specified binary.

Comment: until you get to a line that starts with "----------------------------379412310113082987734398"
Yes, but you can't search for this line :----------------------------379412310113082987734398
It's never the same boundary result

Comment: @Eric The OP's post seems to indicate that it is, but sure, the basic algorithm should be adapted to whatever the actual details (as yet unspecified) are.